# Laravel Cashier Call to a member function stripe() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I have created a product and trying to subscribe user using laravel Cashier. Below the subscriptionProcess method that I have tried. I also share laravel log below.

```
public function subscriptionProcess(Request $request)
{
        
        //dd($request->user()->newSubscription('Author', 'price_1MPP8WSCmMZAfVWiwJlCbVym'));
        $subscription = $request->user()->newSubscription('Author', 'price_1MPP8WSCmMZAfVWiwJlCbVym')->create($request->token);
   
        return view("pages.subscription_success");
}
```

After send the below request

[image]

I have used the card number

```
https://stripe.com/docs/testing
```

Always getting response

```
Laravel Cashier  Call to a member function stripe() on null
```

After `dd($request->user()->newSubscription('Author', 'price_1MPP8WSCmMZAfVWiwJlCbVym'));`

I have got below object

[image]

Laravel Error log has updated below.

```
    [2023-01-12 21:56:53] local.ERROR: Call to a member function stripe() on null {"userId":51,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function stripe() on null at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Subscription.php:1371)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Subscription.php(1271): Laravel\\Cashier\\Subscription->asStripeSubscription(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Concerns/HandlesPaymentFailures.php(28): Laravel\\Cashier\\Subscription->latestPayment()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/SubscriptionBuilder.php(263): Laravel\\Cashier\\SubscriptionBuilder->handlePaymentFailure(Object(Laravel\\Cashier\\Subscription), 'pm_1MPT92SCmMZA...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/AuthorController.php(72): Laravel\\Cashier\\SubscriptionBuilder->create('pm_1MPT92SCmMZA...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthorController->subscriptionProcess(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('subscriptionPro...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(260): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthorController), 'subscriptionPro...')
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(727): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/AuthenticateSession.php(59): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\AuthenticateSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(728): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(705): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(669): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 /var/www/html/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 {main}
"}
```

Comment: This error `Call to a member function stripe() on null` comes from the laravel.log. copy the error *with stacktrace* and paste it in your original question. The stacktrace is needed to resolve your question

Comment: Great job with the laravel.log. put a try/catch around your `price_1MPP8WSCmMZAfVWiwJlCbVym')->create($request->token)`. It will not solve the problem, but you can then catch it earlier. What happens when you do `dd($request->token);`